# PHP Email validate doesn't work and undefined posts

Tags: php, post

So the issue is, no matter what I put in the email text bot, whether it is a valid email or not, it will continue to say, "Please enter a valid email address!" I don't think that the error is with the email valid portion because when I get rid of that section, all of the submission parts say "undefined" when they should run into some the $errors that I defined.

it looks like:

```
localhost says:
Array{
    [regEmail] => undefined
    [regUsername] => undefined
    [regPass] => undefined
    [regRePass] => undefined 
}
```

This is my PHP code:

```
if ($_GET['action'] == "register"){
    $error = "";
    if (!$_POST['regEmail']){
         $error = "An email address is required.";
    } else if (!$_POST['regUsername']) {
        $error = "Please enter a Username.";
    } else if (!$_POST['regPass']){
        $error = "Please enter a Password";
    } else if (!$_POST['regRePass']){
        $error = "Please enter a Password";
    } else if ($_POST['regPass'] != $_POST['regRePass']) {
        $error = "Passwords don't match.";
    } else if (filter_var($_POST['regEmail'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        $error = "Please enter a valid email address!";     
    }

    if($error != "") {
        echo $error;
        exit();
    }

    $queryEmail = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['regEmail'])."'";
    $queryUsername = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['regUsername'])."'";

    $resultEmail = mysqli_query($link, $queryEmail);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($resultEmail) > 0) {
        $error = "That email address is already in use.";
    }

    $resultUsername = mysqli_query($link, $queryUsername);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($resultUsername) > 0) {
        $error = "Sorry, that username is already taken.";
    }       

    print_r($_POST);
}
```

Here is the script sending the post:

```
$("#register").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "actions.php?action=register",
        data: "regEmail=" + $("#regEmail").val() + "&regUsername=" + $("#regUsername").val() + "&regPass=" + $("#regPass").val() + "&regRePass=" + $("#regRePass").val(),
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result)
        }
    })
})
```

If there is any more code that is needed, I will post.

Comment: We don't know what `filter_var($_POST['regEmail'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` does, but clearly it's returning `false`.

Comment: First do `var_dump($_POST);` and see if you're getting all data correctly or not.

Comment: What does the request in your Developer Tools look like? Are parameters all sent the correct way? I suppose you could try splitting the `$.ajax` `data` parameter: `data: { a:"1", b:"2" ]` instead of `data: "a=1&b=2"` -- not sure though

Comment: I think my issue is I'm not getting all of the data correctly. When I do a `var_dump($_POST)` everything comes up `string(9) "undefined"`. I'm still trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
if (!isset($_POST['regEmail'])){
```

Also, try sending your data like this:

```
data: ({
    regEmail: $("#regEmail").val(),
    regUsername: $("#regUsername").val(),
    ...
})
```

Comment: Changing it to `!isset` doesn't fix any issue, and when I change the way I send the data, nothing is echoed at all.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what the issue was. In my `<input>` I had `name="regEmail"`, `name="regUsername"` etc, and when I changed it to `id="regEmail"`,`id="regUsername"`... the issue resolved itself.